# I wanna create model which Before adding it must be accepted

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to create a model which must be accepted by the moderator before adding, after which every change in eg the title in this model must also be accepted

```
class MangaRequest(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=191)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=TYPE, blank=True, default='', null=True)
   status= models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS, blank=True, default='', null=True)
   date_start = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   data_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   age_restrictions = models.ForeignKey(OgraniczenieWiekowe, null=True, default='', blank=True)
   volumes = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
   chapter = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
   is_accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is my model and I have done it

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_accept == True:
       manga = MangaAccept.objects.create(...)
       super(MangaRequest, self).delete()
       return manga
        else:
            super(MangaRequest, self).save()
```

And the same way is about `deletes`
My question is how can ACCEPT or REJECT for model and everyone field in this model ? Any sugestion ?

Comment: The simple way to add boolean field to your model `is_verified=...(default=False)` and in your views filter only moderated requests will be shown.

Comment: With fields - may be try add boolean field `has_unsubmitted_changes` and JSONField `tmp_changes_storage`, where temporarily store changes before moderation and after - override model fields and remove tmp data from that JSONField.

Comment: At the moment i have `is_acceptt = false' but its good way with JSON if wanna create system with points, if someone edit e.g the title or create new give him points example for create 5. So with this json should be work ?